# Can 35mm film be developed if it's been ripped out of canister?

Tags: film, pentax, developing, pentax-k1000

I am a total beginner and my Pentax K 1000 has jammed a few times. Being the noob I am I ripped the film from the canister. I have the film rolls but the film itself is not in the canister. Can I still develop the film?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Film works by changing when exposed to light.  If you have exposed the film to light, then any information it captured will be lost as the film will have been completely over-exposed and washed out.  If you did it in complete darkness or, if it's orthochromatic, limited spectrum of light to which the film isn't sensitive (like the red lights in a dark room) then you'd be ok, but it doesn't sound like that's the case here.

Comment: Most modern film emulsions are __panchromatic__, i.e. sensitive to the whole spectrum of visible light, therefore they should be handled in complete darkness! __Orthochromatic__ films, on the other hand, are sensitive only to green and blue parts of the light spectrum, so they can be handled under a red darkroom safelight.

Comment: @lightproof - good to know.  I know the basics of film, but I got serious after film had already passed it's prime so I never personally got a chance to learn darkroom work.

Answer (score 2):

If you've done this in absolute darkness and kept the film in absolute darkness: Yes, absolutely.

If it received some light: no.